# Passing WordPress credentials not Working. Please assist

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, authentication, single-sign-on

After beating myself over the head for the last weeks, I need to ask for some help. In theory this should be simple.

I am attempting to create a WordPress SSO for a custom Login System. When a user logs on to the WordPress Website ( or (changes the password or the email) it will fire up the SSO functions after the user has been validated by Wordpress.

My question is which direct hook is correct to use for this task and what variable(s) are good to utilize for this task. When a guest logs into Wordpress, successfully, it then uses the same credentials of the user to validate the Custom System Login.

```
function custom_login() {
//## Function used to 'Auto' Login to Custom if user is accepted from WordPress.


    //## Check if user is signed on.
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {

       //## User is Not Logged in, return 'false'
       return;

    }


    //## Assign Varibles (is this too risky?)
    //## Not sure if the $_POST['value'] will be the best way for this.
    $NewUserCred_username  = $_POST['log'];
    $NewUserCred_password  = $_POST['pwd'];


    //## Fire up Custom Validation. 
    //## Will set Custom Session if Successful.
    fireCustomLoginFunction($NewUserCred_username, $NewUserCred_password);


}


//## Maybe should run this during wp_signon or wp_login?
add_action( 'NOT SURE', 'custom_login' );
```

It would seem wp_signon is the one to use somehow as it contains credentials that I need to use to pass to the function before they are hashed, but at that time the user has not be validated. The custom system re-Hashes the Information for security.

My question is which direct hook is correct to use for this task and what variable(s) are good to utilize for this task. Any ideas? Any feedback is truly appreciated

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login', 100 );

function custom_login() {
   //## Function used to 'Auto' Login to Custom if user is accepted from WordPress.


//## Check if user is signed on.
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {

   //## User is Not Logged in, return 'false'
   return;

}


//## Assign Varibles (is this too risky?)
//## Not sure if the $_POST['value'] will be the best way for this.
$NewUserCred_username  = $_POST['user_login'];
$NewUserCred_password  = $_POST['user_email'];


//## Fire up Custom Validation. 
//## Will set Custom Session if Successful.
fireCustomLoginFunction($NewUserCred_username, $NewUserCred_password);


}
```

Comment: If I use **after_setup_theme** then the user is not authenticated by WordPress though right?

Comment: it depends which hook was used to use wp_signon. If its `after _setup_theme`, the priority of 100 should mean it runs after any hooks with the default priority of 10. You just want any hook after they have signed on.

Comment: its not passing any values at all. I can see its trying to execute. any Ideas?

Comment: did you echo out the $_POST values? if yes - its your other function which you haven't shown above.

Comment: First off, that a Million for helping me. It has the $_POST as empty. Maybe, I am using the wrong $_POST value. Let me ask you this, what should  $NewUserCred_username  = $_POST['log']; be if not that post value?

Comment: Its passing blank values to the 'fireCustomLoginFunction'.

Comment: you see it depends on the login form used. If i create a form that uses ajax $_POST will obviously be empty (i assume you var_dump($_POST) to see what is passed? ) or there could be a redirect before the hook is called in which case $_POST is not carried forward! If you post your login form and handling code i may be able to help more

Comment: As for the form, I am using the basic one provided from WP (wp-login.php), even at the very basic form provided I can not get it to pass values.Let me compile a testing code for posting to see if that helps and i will post that for you.

Comment: i changed the post fields for you. According to wp-login.php they should be the correct ones!

Comment: Tried and tried. The $NewUserCred_username and $NewUserCred_password are totally empty. Do i need to maybe change the "after_setup_theme"?

Comment: first place this in the function `var_dump($_POST); exit;` report back on what it outputs.

Comment: So I tested it in a million new ways. your request is the following : `array(0) { }`

Comment: ok now you have a problem.....you need to add a hook before the create user function and grab the values and save in a $_SESSION and recall again in the function above.